# use multiple options for multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to plot two (or more) graphs that have the same plot-options. The code will look like

```
plot(data1, type='l', lwd=2, col=c(1,1,2,1,3,1), pch=19)
plot(data2, type='b', lwd=2, col=c(1,1,2,1,3,1), pch=19)
```

It would be nice if I can keep some options in variables. The code will look like

```
my_opt <- list(lwd=2, col=c(1,1,2,1,3,1), pch=19)
plot(data1, type='l', my_opt)   ## it does not work
plot(data2, type='b', my_opt)
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `do.call`, with do.call you can do a lot of things, one of them to pass the arguments in the form of list.

```
data1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = (1:10)**2)
data2  <- data.frame(x = seq(1,10,2), y = 1:5)

my_opt <- list(lwd=2, col=c(1,1,2,1,3,1), pch=19)
do.call(plot, c(data1, type ="l", my_opt) )  
do.call(plot, c(data2, type ="b", my_opt) )
```

[image]

Comment: do.call is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a small wrapper function instead

```
myplot <- function(mydata, ...){
 plot(mydata, lwd = 2, col = c(1,1,2,1,3,1), pch = 19, ...)
}

myplot(data1, type = "l")
myplot(data2, type = "b")
```